# How to see if a drop down element is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript, and I want to print out a selected item from a drop down menu.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<fieldset>
    <label>3. Select your operating system</label>&nbsp;
    <select class="form-control" name="Os">
        <option selected="selected" value="select one">- select one -</option>
        <optgroup label="Basic">
            <option value="OSX">Mac OSX</option>
            <option value="windows">Windows</option> 
        </optgroup> 
        <optgroup label="Advanced">
            <option value="linux">Linux</option>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</fieldset>
```

My javascript code is:

```
<script type= text/javascript>
    var e = document.getElementByName("Os");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.writeln(strUser);
</script>
```

For some reason it won't print the selected value. Any ideas?

Comment: the value of selectedIndex will give you the answer, regardless of the value of the option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementByName`, it's `getElementsByName` and it gets a nodeList

```
var strUser = document.getElementsByName("Os")[0].value;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/eu2pE/)

and make sure the script tag comes after the elements in the DOM